# ASP.net MVC - Authorize controller for one user/role but all users for one action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller like this:

```
[Authorize(Users="Admin")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    ...

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public AllUsersAction()
    {

    }
}
```

Except I actually do want to authorize `AllUsersAction`, only all authorized users should be able to hit it, not just Admin.

What to do?

**EDIT:** I know that I can authorize the whole controller and provide more restrictions for all actions that should only be available to `Admin`. But I'd rather not put attributes on every action but one.

The question could be better phrased: What would an implementation look like that would allow this 'minimalism' if it isn't currently possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use Authorize attribute without any parameters for controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    ...
    public AllUsersAction()
    {

    }

    [Authorize(Users="Admin")]
    public ActionResult OnlyForAdmin()
    {
    }

}
```

And specify Authorize attribute Roles/Users properties for restricted actions.

Unfortunately Authorize attribute on controller bypasses authorization only if action has AllowAnonymous attribute. Fortunately you can override OnAuthorization method of Authorize attribute to skip authorization check in controller Authorize attribute if action has its own Authorize attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true)) 
        {
            //skip authorization check if action has Authorize attribute
            return;
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

You can use this CustomAuthorize in your example:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Users="Admin")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    ...

    [Authorize]
    public AllUsersAction()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Right. I do understand that I can do that, but what I'm after is a way to do this with the least amount of code possible. I could also move my non-admin actions to another controller. Do you know if what I'm asking for can be done with the current infrastructure? If not, what might it look like to implement an improvement that would allow for what I want?

Comment: There is no ready solution in MVC for that. You can override Authorize attribute's OnAuthorization method to skip authoriztion if action has it own Authorize attribute. Check edits.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on an approach to approximate it!